# For each parsing a list as a value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform

The list will not be parsed into the resource as a value in terraform.

Tried different processing terms for the value in the list.

```
module 
resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  for_each = var.records_list

  zone_id = var.zone_id
  name    = each.key
  type    = lookup(each.value, "type", "A")
  ttl     = lookup(each.value, "ttl", "60")
  records = [ lookup(each.value, "records", "8.8.8.8") ]
}

Module call

module "example" {
  source = "../../modules/coreDNS/"
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.example.id

  records_list = var.example
}

Variable pasred in

variable "example" {
  default = {
    rebot = {
      ttl = "60"
      type  = "A"
      records  = [ "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ]
    }
  }
  description = "This is a list for"
  type = map(map(any))
}
```

I expect the value `[ "1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2" ]` to be parsed into the terraform module for creating a route 53 entry and creating an A record, however no record is created.

Comment: What does happen? Does it error? If not can you show the plan after running a destroy?

Comment: This is hard to follow. What is the variable records_list? And because there was a bug some versions ago, which version of terraform are you using?